# How to Show standard date time field in vf page

Tags: visualforce

How to show the standard date time functionality in vf page.
[image]

Comment: If you are trying to input to a `Datetime` field, just use `apex:inputField`

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, but it won't *render* the same as the screenshot. That's sort of the ask here. See `/00U/e` versus `<apex:page standardController="Event">
    <apex:form>
     <apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Event.StartDateTime}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [apex:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm) does not provide this functionality and I was not able to find apex tag that offers it.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to use input tags like this example

```
<apex:page standardController="Event">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Event.StartDateTime}" showDatePicker="true" required="true"/>
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Start" for="eventstartdate"/>
                    <input type ="date" id="eventstartdate" value="{!Event.StartDateTime}"/>
                    <input type ="time" value="{!Event.StartDateTime}"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> </apex:page>
```

This is the result:

[image]

It doesn't look like exactly the same as Standard UI, but it could be a solution.

Alternatively, you can create a Date field and use apex:inputField with it and *showdatepicker=false* in order to hide it and *required=true* to show the red bar. Then create a custom controller in order to get it and save on StartDateTime field. 
But I didn't find the solution for the time part.

Answer (score 1):

Several years ago, I did a PDF template in an org that I believe had what you're asking for. I no longer have access to that org to go back and look for the details, but I'm fairly certain they did it using a custom component.

In the code I used for the PDF, they had something that looked like this:

```
<c:DateComponent fecha="{!opp.Tracking_Date__c}"></c:DateComponent>
```

I'm also pretty confident that `opp.Tracking_Date__c` was a datetime custom field.

That suggests to me that you'd need to create custom components that would look something like this:

```
    <c:DateComponent fecha="{!opp.Tracking_Date__c}"></c:DateComponent>
    <c:TimeComponent fecha="{!opp.Tracking_Date__c}"></c:TimeComponent>
```

I've not had time to fully finish this, but here's the gist of what I think you need to do:

Custom Component for Date:

```
<apex:component >
     <apex:attribute name="fecha" type="datetime"  description="output date component of date-time value"/>
  <apex:outputText value="{record!DateValue}"/> 
</apex:component>
```

Custom Component for Time:

```
<apex:component >
     <apex:attribute name="fecha" type="datetime"  description="output time component of date-time value"/>
  <apex:outputText value="{record!TimeValue}"/> 
</apex:component>
```

Common Controller:

```
public class MyCustomDateTimeController {
    public datetime ControllerValue{get;}
    public string DateValue{set;}
    public string TimeValue{set;}


    public static string SplitDateValue(datetime dt) {
        datetime ControllerValue;
        if(dt == null) ControllerValue = System.Now();

        date d = ControllerValue.date();
        string DateValue = string.valueOf(d); 

        Return DateValue;
        Return TimeValue;

   }

   public static string SplitTimeValue(datetime dt) {
        datetime ControllerValue;
        if(dt == null) ControllerValue = System.Now();

        Time tm = ControllerValue.time();
        string TimeValue = string.valueOf(tm);

        Return TimeValue;

   }


}
```

**Note:** I've not had time to finish this or get it fully working. The controller may need to be split into two separate controllers; one for each of the components. Each one, will probably also need a separate getter and setter method.

That said, this is the gist of how I believe you can accomplish what you're asking. I've never created a custom component along these lines before, so am a bit slow in working out the minutia with this. Just the same, I thought it worth passing along as I'm busy with other things at the moment and didn't want you to have to wait on me to finish.